# how to remove class attribute in selected text range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, range

i need to remove class attribute from the selected text(selected text means user will select some range of text by mouse). if the selected text has the **class='ansspans'**, then we need to remove that class for that particular selected text. ( i am using this in gridview, so many rows will be there, so i need to remove class for that particular selected text)

```
 <span id="sss_ctl00_ctl06_lblAnswerText" class="Label"> 
      <span>ssss</span><span class="ansspans">assignment</span>submission
 </span>
```

1. if User Selects  `assignment` from the page, which already has class='anspans', then if he click button(to reset highlighted marking), then for that particular selected text, we should remove the class attribute. after clicking the button.

Output

```
  <span id="sss_ctl00_ctl06_lblAnswerText" class="Label"> 
       <span>ssss</span><span>assignment</span>submission
 </span>
```

here why i am doing this,

1. Basically user will select some word and mark some word. (marking and highlighting is all done, n working fine ) ( imagine he selects 3 words)
2. Now user wants to remove the one of the highlighted word, then he selects the word, then click reset button. then for that selected text, class attribute will be removed. which i am facing problem.

**Update : Even i tried one of my friends solution like this. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VAH6T/2/)**  - still not working for my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Rangy-specific version of this is solved on the Rangy forum. Code is quite lengthy so not reproduced here. http://groups.google.com/group/rangy/browse_thread/thread/5738cf7bc32c607a

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/URms2/

Comment: i done it before, using your documentation :) , +1 for awesome libray. saved hundred line of code :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add are remove class by using jQuery methods. Please refer for [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

and for [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Comment: i am telling for selected text, can you come up with example. i know adding and remove class

Comment: added some code--- http://jsfiddle.net/8Y7Rk/1/ , where i used selected class for selected text

Comment: not working, and i need to select the text first, then click the button, read whole question

Comment: none of your example work, and you need to read, i am telling again and again, i need to select the word first, then remove that class